# Create a transition table

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

I am trying to create a transition table for a markov chain but I have difficulties. Consider a game, where each player (of two, lets call them A and B) has a fixed given probability of scoring 3 points, scoring 5 points and scoring 7 points. The probabilies for each player are called `p3A,p5A,p7A` and `p3B,p5B,p7B` and finally the probability of zero points for both of them is `pZero`. This game has 80 rounds. At the end of 1st round, the score difference will be: `+3, +5, +7 , -3, -5, -7, 0` (score difference is defined as `score A - Score B`).  Only one player or no player can score in each round. There is no possibility of both players scoring at the same round. 
Lets call score difference at round R, D :

```
dif(R,D)
```

apparently :

```
dif(1,0)=pZero
dif(1,3)=p3A
dif(1,5)=p5A
dif(1,7)=p7A
dif(1,-3)=p3B
dif(1,-5)=p5B
dif(1,-7)=p7B

dif(1,x)=0 for every other x
```

so at round 2:

```
dif(2,14)=dif(1,7)*p7A
dif(2,13)=dif(1,6)*p7A + dif(1,8)*p5A + dif(1,10)*p3A + dif(1,13)*pZero + dif(1,16)*p3B + dif(1,18)*p5B + dif(1,20)*p7B = 0*p7A + 0*.....=0
```

and so on.

You can tell the pattern, it could easily be rewritten as recursive function. What I want though is to ind the transition table. Apparently at the end of game, at round 80, you can have a difference that varies from +560 to -560.

All examples I have found offer my examples for simple random walks, but not something that complex. I cannot figure out which the states are, and how to generate transition table. Any ideas?Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try modeling this as a Markov chain with rewards. The states would be the possible outcomes for a single round, while the reward for a state would be net change in the score.

Comment: In which case the score difference is $3$? can the score difference be $2$? I am having trouble understanding the game.

Comment: @ConradoCosta The score difference can be 3 for example if at round one player A scores 3 points (`p3A`), or maybe at round 3 after having 2 rounds of players A scoring `p3A` and `p3A` and then player B `p3B`. This can be done in 3 ways,  `p3A*p3A*p3B`, `p3A*p3B*p3A`, `p3B*p3A*p3A`. As you go on apparently problem becomes more complicated and thr set of possible values for score difference increases (at the end of round 1 it can be: `-7,-5,-3,0,3,5,7` while at the end or round 2 it can be:` -14,-12,-10,-8,-6,-3,3,6,8,10,12,14`) and so on..

Comment: @amd thanks, though I didn't understand exactly what you mean. Could you give an example for just 2 first rounds?

Comment: Now that I’ve thought about it a bit more, I’m not sure that you’d really learn much about the game this way. A MC with rewards would be good for computing things like the expected score difference after $n$ rounds, but since the probabilities don’t depend on the current state (i.e., the points awarded in the previous round), that expectation can be computed directly from the probabilities and payoffs without needing to use a transition matrix. It’s probably better to continue to investigate random walks instead. What is it that you want to find out about this game?

Comment: @amd I need to calculate the probability of winner, that is `Sum[dif[80,i],{i,1,560}]` for playerA, but using recursive formulas this is time consuming. So I was hoping that using matrices would improve my efficiency.

Comment: If player A scores  3 points then player B scores 0?

Comment: @ConradoCosta correct. You are right, I am going to edit my original question, since it was not clear. There can be only one playerscoring in each round, or no player, but not both players. Apologies for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to model a random walk like this as a Markov chain uses an uncountably infinite state space, namely $\mathbb Z$. The transition probabilities would be $$p_{i,i+7}=p_{7A}, p_{i,i+5}=p_{5A}, \dots, p_{i,i-5}=p_{5B}, p_{i,i-7}=p_{7B},$$ with all others zero. Since the state space isn’t finite, there’s no transition matrix. If you limit the number of steps, you could conceivably create a transition matrix (taking care to make sure that the effects of the edges were correct), but I’m not sure that’s going to simplify your computations since this matrix would be quite large. It is mostly empty, with the probabilities running down a few diagonals around the main diagonal, so perhaps you could take advantage of that to simplify computing powers of this matrix.

I have a feeling that a more fruitful approach to solving your problem—compute the probability that player A wins after $n$ rounds—would be to examine the returns to zero of this walk. The last return is the important one, so if you can figure out the probability of that occurring at round $k$, you can sum over the number of rounds and multiply by $P(X_i>0)=p_{A3}+p_{A5}+p_{A7}$.

Comment: I can already calculate what I need, but without using the transition table. That was the challenge, and the reason why I cannot, is because state 1 of my matrix is difference =0, but then I don't know how to continue. Which state is 2 and so on. Since difference can become negative too. Defining states is my issue. Furthermore, the are actually finite, since the difference is an integer number $$ s\in [-560,560] $$

Comment: @Vasilis Well, there’s your answer, then: you have 1121 states, give or take a few impossible scores, so the transition matrix will have on the order of $10^6$ entries. Although most of them will be zero, there’ll still be around 6,000 non-zero entries. Unless there’s a clever way to take advantage of the arrangement of those values, I don’t see this making your computation any simpler. As far as defining these states, do the most straightforward thing: state $i$ represents a score difference of $i-561$.

Comment: thanks for your help,I will think about it, and try to automate it.

Comment: If i consider that state 1 is where I start from (tie, difference =0) then there is a problem, since according to your rational state 1 represents score difference 1-561=560. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @Vasilis What’s the problem? State labels are arbitrary. In this scheme, the state labeled “1” represents a difference of $-560$, so don’t start there. Start in the state that represents a tied game. More precisely, start with a probability vector that has a $1$ in that position and zeros everywhere else.

Comment: I was not aware of having such freedom in defining states. Thought I had to be formalist by starting from state 1. Thanks @amd